# JTable refresh are not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm desperately trying to convince my `JTable` to refresh when I change its data. The data are stored in a global singleton, `TreeSet`, that I'm working with. Whenever the `TreeSet`s data is altered, an event is fired to refresh the `TableModel`. For test purposes, I replaced this by a simple `Timer` firing events.

Each time an event is fired, an element from the `TreeSet` is removed to simulate changes in the data. The event fires and the `TableClass` receives it and processes it as expected, but when it comes to refreshing nothing happens. I tried to create a new `TableModel` each time an event occurs and set it to the global table. The changes to the singleton `TreeSet` are made but nothing happens to the `JTable`.

```java
public class TreeTableObj implements ActionListener{
public JTable table ;

public TreeTableObj(){
    MyTableModel myModel = new MyTableModel(getValuesOfTreeSet(), getTreeSetRows());

    table = new JTable( myModel){ //some rendering };

    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames;
        private Object[][] data ;


        public MyTableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames){
            this.data = data;
            this.columnNames = columnNames;
            System.out.println("Model created");
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public void setData(Object[][] data){
            this.data = data;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }


        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }


        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (true) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (true) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    public void refreshTableModel(){
        FlightsTreeSet.getInstance().remove(FlightsTreeSet.getInstance().first());
        table.setModel(new MyTableModel(getValuesOfTreeSet(), getTreeSetRows()));
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        refreshTableModel();    
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**[EDIT1]**

I am getting closer to the problems Core:
I found out that the table which is displayed in the JFrame holds another reference as the one that I change. I made all changes visible and they apply to the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. And leaving the answer here to be found by others...
After realizing that the displayed `JTable` and the one that I was editing hold different references (see [EDIT1]) I found out that I was creating two different Objects of the `JTable`. One to be displayed and the other one in `main()` to become an `ActionListener`. The Listener received the Events and did the changes but the other one never noticed that anything was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Is something missing in your code? Your table model as it is shouldn't compile, because it is missing all the methods that JTable would use to access the data (`getColumnCount()`, `getValueAt()`, etc.)

Also, you shouldn't have to create a new model on every change - just have the model `fireTableStructureChanged()`.

Comment: fireTableDataChanged() would be a better fitting event if the change in the set doesn't require a change in table columns.

Comment: I tried that out by calling the setData(Object[][] data) method. Inside the method i call the fireTableDataChanged() method. But guess what? Still nothing happens.