# How to notify a JTable to Update its Model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, treeset

I'm looking for a pattern to notify my `JTable` that the Data which are handled in the TableModel have changed. The Idea is that I got a global singleton `TreeSet` managing the Data. I receive randomly updates on the `TreeSet`.If any changes are made to the TreeSet the `TableModel`should update itself by gathering the new information from the TreeSet.

Observer? Events + Listener? anything else?

Thank you for your help!

ps: A way to update the Model is already implemented and is NOT part of the Question.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10516213/1329572. Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically answered your own question, observer, event + listeners. A change from the usual: **have** you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Question was a little confusing, but it sounds like you should be using `AbstractTableModel.fireTableDataChanged()`, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Listening for Data Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange)

Consider the method `fireTableStructureChanged`. You can see an example in [CustomEditorTableModel](https://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/IDE-Netbeans/vmd.analyzer/org/netbeans/modules/vmd/midpnb/propertyeditors/table/CustomEditorTableModel.java.htm)

And you can see another in [SortingaColumninaJTableComponent](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SortingaColumninaJTableComponent.htm)

Comment: sorry for not making it clear but I already can Update the model that was not the question. (as you see in the last line of my question)