# How to refresh JInternalFrame Or JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jinternalframe

I have `JInternalFrame` contains `JTable`. How can I refresh `JInternalFrame` 
Or `JTable` when click `JButton ---> update`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516213/jtable-refresh-are-not-displayed

Comment: Maybe create a `TableModel` and use `fireTableStructureChanged()`

Answer (score 2):

When you update your `TableModel`, the `JTable` should refresh itself automatically. If not, your `TableModel` should be corrected, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to call `.repaint()` in the actionlistener. For example:

```
public class RefreshingButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JComponent componentToRefsesh;

    public RefreshingButton(JComponent toRefresh) {
        super("Refresh JTable");
        this.componentToRefsesh = toRefresh;
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        componentToRefsesh.repaint();
    }
}
```

The best way is to use the Model-View-Controller design pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: AFAIK repaint are for Graphics(2D), notify LayoutManager after changes into Components Tree, the same in this for doLayout or notify

Comment: no. a) don't subclass a JSomething, instead use it b) don't expose api that's not meant for public usage (here's that the actionListener callback), instead instantiate/implement the listener internally and use it c) most of the time a repaint appears to be needed, somthing is wrong with the setup